# multiple grapics2d objects

Tags: java, awt, java-2d, affinetransform

I need to apply different Affine Transform to different graphic objects(eg lines), is it suitable to use multiple  Graphics2D objects to perform this task?
Code:

```
   Graphics2D g2seconds = (Graphics2D) g; // g - Graphics class
   Graphics2D g2minutes = (Graphics2D) g;

   AffineTransform atseconds =  
           AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(Math.PI/30*s, 0, 0);//s = Time in seconds
   AffineTransform atminutes =  
           AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(Math.PI/30*m, 0, 0);//m = Time in minutes

   g2seconds.setTransform(atseconds);
   g2seconds.drawLine(0, 0, 10, 10);

   g2minutes .setTransform(atminutes);
   g2minutes .drawLine(0, 0, 10, 10);
```

Comment: Just change the transform between drawing them.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

No, because those aren't two distinct objects at all, they are two references to the same object.